# How to connect laptop to CRT TV

Tags: laptop, tv, crt

I have a Panasonic Quintrix CRT TV which has SCART point and I have a Sony Vaio laptop with VGA 15 pin and HDMI USB port. Planning to connect my laptop to tv using following items,

Option 1
SCART to RCA adaptor which I will connect to my TV
15 PIN VGA to RCA cable which I will plug into RCA ports in the adaptor.

Option 2
SCART to RCA adaptor which I will connect to my TV
HDMI to RCA cable which I will plug into RCA ports in the adaptor.

Will any of the options above work?

Thanks
Mani

Comment: The scart connection itself could carry many signal types, as its design was to be universal. One of those is Analog VGA, but the TV does not have to have analog VGA connection, or ability to use VGA to have a SCART connection on the back. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scart  ** What is the Model number of the Television? **  Does the manuel present that it takes a RGB analog?  Usually only "pro" type models of crts had that ability here in the US.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get a decent picture (from a computer or game console) out of an old CRT monitor is to use RGB connectors. A CRT TV is a fixed-sync RGB monitor, even if it does not have a VGA port. Most SCART connectors have RGB input (usually only one, and they are usually labeled "RGB"). Sometimes the CRT has coaxial RGB input, so you need to check the backside of your TV.

Using RCA connectors will give extremely bad picture (think VHS quality), but I suppose RGB adapters are getting quite hard to come by these days (they used to be very common during the CRT era). There seems to be plenty of cheap adapters on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?scart%20rgb%20vga&_nkw=scart%20rgb%20vga) though.

Answer (score 0):

both may work, depends on your TV, `HDMI` used for higher quality and `VGA` gives bit lower quality output,  most of TV supports VGA, first try VGA